# Delete some oldest commits that includes data files

Tags: git

I have a remote git repository. The remote includes a bunch of commits. I have pushed my dataset (data files almost 3 GB) to remote by mistake. I want to remove/delete some oldest commits that includes dataset in both local and remote repository in order to reduce the size of the repository. The `git log --oneline` prints:

```
993ebd6 last commit
cd882ce blah blah blah
...     ...
289a7dd blah blah blah
d750b6c data file ignored (added to .gitignore)
8005019 repo still includes data files
2a85665 repo still includes data files
83601d3 data added!
89b7a4a initial commit
```

What I want to do is deleting commits which includes data files (between `d750b6c` to `89b7a4a`). I mean it need to delete not only commits but also the files in related commit. As far as I know, `git reset --hard` does deletion however it only deletes the local files and causes error when a shared remote repository exists.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: git reset --hard doesn _not_ delete anything.... at least, not from the repo/revisions.. it can definitely delete stuff from the working tree. Then, I think we need more clarity. You want to remove a file that was added on revision *d750b6c*?

Comment: Basically, I want to reduce the size of my repo, therefore I need to remove commits (that include `data` folder) from the remote repository. So some other people can clone the repo without large data files.

Answer (score 1):

Without `--graph`, `git log --oneline` omits some information.  The omitted information *may* be important here.  It *probably is* but it could be irrelevant.  Let's assume it is relevant, and draw it.

Let's look at *what Git stores* (without bothering too much for now about the *how* part).  What Git stores, to a first approximation anyway, is *commits*.  Each commit contains a full and complete snapshot of *all files*—well, all files that existed in Git's *index* at the time you made the commit.  So your big data file is in commit `83601d3` (`data added!`).  It's *also* in commits `2a85665` and `8005019`.  It may also be in `d750b6c` (the one labeled `data file ignored (added to .gitignore)` here), because adding a *name* to `.gitignore` does not change the absence or presence of the file in the index.<sup>1</sup>  Listing the file in `.gitignore` mostly just shuts up `git status`, telling it not to complain if the file is in the work-tree, but is not in the index.

But the saved snapshot is not the *only* thing in a commit.  Each commit also saves some *metadata*—some data about the saved snapshot.  For instance, each commit you make has your name and email address.  It has your log message—the information you had Git save about *why* you made this commit, so that you can see what you were thinking at the time.  It has a date-and-time stamp.  And, crucially, it has the *hash ID*—such as `83601d3` (but at full 40-character length)—of its *parent* commit.

Git looks up commits by these hash IDs.  In effect, the IDs are the real names of the commit.  Each ID is unique to that specific commit.  In fact, the ID is formed by computing a crypotgraphic hash over the *contents* of the commit—so this means that the *parent* ID of a child commit is a crucial part of the *identity* of the child.  Remember that, in the back of your head, while we take a moment to draw this chain of commits:

```
993ebd6 last commit
   ↓

cd882ce blah blah blah
   ↓
...     ...
   ↓

289a7dd blah blah blah
   ↓

d750b6c data file ignored (added to .gitignore)
   ↓

8005019 repo still includes data files
   ↓

2a85665 repo still includes data files
   ↓

83601d3 data added!
   ↓

89b7a4a initial commit
```

Embedded within each commit, in other words, is a sort of backwards arrow (or downwards in this vertical drawing).  Adding `--graph` to `git log`, with or without `--oneline`, makes Git draw the same sort of arrows / lines (using mostly a vertical bar `|` to connect `*` markers at each commit, with the arrow direction implied instead of drawn in).

The other thing to realize is that because the hash ID is exquisitely sensitive to every bit of data *in* the commit, if you try to *change* the commit—for instance, by removing a file from it—what you get is not a *changed* commit but rather a *new and different* commit.  The new commit may well be *better*, but it has a different hash ID.

So, let's replace bad commit `83601d3` with a new, better one.  We don't know, yet, what its hash ID is, but we can draw it anyway:

```
2a85665 repo still includes data files
   ↓
83601d3 data added!                       XXXXXXX improved: no extra data
   ↓                                         │
89b7a4a initial commit                 ←─────┘
```

So ... that's fine, but now we need to re-copy `2a85665` too.  We would anyway because it still has the big file(s) so we must make a new-and-improved commit that doesn't have them.  The *parent* of the new and improved `2a85665` will have some new hash ID `YYYYYYYY`.

Now we have to copy `8005019` too, minus the big file(s).  And then, because that gets a new hash ID, we *definitely* have to copy `d750b6c` too, *even if `d750b6c` doesn't have the big file(s)*.  We have to make a new copy that has the new hash ID as its parent.

Having copied `d750b6c`, we must copy *its* child, to—again—replace the parent hash ID, if nothing else.  This ripples on down through every other commit until we reach `993ebd6`.  Having copied that one, we have a new chain ending at whatever this new hash is.  We have Git replace the hash ID `993ebd6` stored under the name `master` (or whatever branch name you are using) with the latest replacement-commit's hash ID, essentially "forgetting" the original chain of commits.

This operation—making some change to some early commit, then having that change ripple down through the entire chain of commits, copying-and-replacing *each one* with a new and improved version—is what `git rebase` is built to do.  With `git rebase -i` you get a chance to fix an earlier commit, then have all subsequent commits copied to new-and-improved versions.  The result is a new chain of commits and everyone who was using the old chain—you in your Git repository, but also everyone else who has a *separate* Git repository, such as the one at `origin`—need to switch to the new chain.  For you, that's just a matter of using `git push --force` to update your remote at `origin`.

---

<sup>1</sup>For a lot more about the index, aka the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*, see other articles that describe how Git builds a new commit from whatever is in the index at the time.  This is how Git's snapshots come about: you copy flies into the index, and then run `git commit`.  The copy-into-index step is what actually compresses and Git-ifies the file, making it ready to *be* committed.  After that, Git keeps taking the Git-ified files out of commits and copying them into the index, so that they're ready to go into the *next* commit.

It's the presence of the file in the index that determines whether the file is *tracked*.  You can use `git rm --cached` to remove the file from the index without removing it from the work-tree: now it's untracked, i.e., not in the index, and therefore won't be in the *next* commit, unless you do something like choose an existing commit that has the file so that Git copies the file back into the index again.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following example which seems to work.

supposedly i have my commits `master` of repository d1:

```
* 20e4a1f added c.txt
* 79422f7 removed big file
* bc0d9c7 added b.txt
* 5b0c75d big file
* 5a8df10 initial
```

a big file was added in `5b0c75d` and removed in `79422f7`. something had happen in the middle and after.

The following set of actions does  the work:

```
git checkout 5a8df10  -b update
git cherry-pick bc0d9c7 
git cherry-pick 20e4a1f
```

now create another rpository 'd2' and pull new brunch in it.

```
cd ../d2
git init
git pull ../d1 update
```

now your d2 repository will be much smaller.

Of course, you need to resolve all the conflicts on the way. However `git checkout --theirs` seems to work universally in this case.

you will definitely lose history of the skipped commits.